# How to Un-Garble Unicode Characters in a CSV Loaded by Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, csv, character-encoding

I have a set of CSV files that may contain special characters.  When I open these files in a text editor, they display without a hitch.  However, when I open these files in Excel, it interprets the special characters as Windows's version of ANSI (I think), converting them to 2-3 different characters instead.  Please see the below image for what various unicode characters (shown in table format with their code points specified by the left column and top row) are converted to.

[Excel representations of unicode characters in a CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FsT5.png)

How can I convert these back into the original characters?  I am fine with using either formulas or VBA.

NOTE: I have seen some answers where prepending a ZWNBSP to the CSV file fixes it.  The trouble with this solution is that I am receiving these files from an external source, so I (or my users) would have to prepend the character manually each time.  Is there some other way?

Thank you!

I have tried using the StrConv function, but it does not seem to work.

```
Sub MyTest()
    Dim s0 As String
    Dim s1 As String
    Dim s2 As String

    s0 = ChrW(192)                  ' Correct character: À
    '                               ' This would appear normally when opening
    '                               ' the file in a text editor
    Debug.Print s0

    s1 = ChrW(195) & ChrW(8364)     ' ANSI representation of s0: Ã€
    '                               ' This is what would appear when opening
    '                               ' the file in Excel
    Debug.Print s1

    s2 = StrConv(s1, vbFromUnicode) ' Returns ?
    Debug.Print s2

    s2 = StrConv(s1, vbUnicode)     ' Returns Ã ¬
    Debug.Print s2
End Sub
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/280603/how-to-set-character-encoding-when-opening-a-csv-file-in-excel

Comment: Load unicode csv into Excel with Power Query. Change `File Origin` to `Unicode`. _Microsoft documentation:_

> [Text/CSV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/text-csv?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: You cannot `convert them back`. You need to import the CSV file properly, using either Power Query or the legacy wizard, and set the proper encoding at that point.

Comment: Well that's just... kind of maddening, to be honest!  So instead of being able to do this automatically with formulas or VBA, I have to train my users to use the data import tool.  Yuck.  Nonetheless, thank you all for your answers!  I appreciate the information.

Answer (score 0):

What seems to have happened to the data is that it was encoded in UTF-8 but interpreted as codepage 1252 (Microsoft's extended version of ISO 8859-1), e.g. codepoint 192 was encoded as the UTF-8 byte sequence `[195, 128]`, which was then decoded as codepage 1252 into the codepoints `[195, 8364]`.

This should be fixable by reversing the encoding and decoding steps.

Example in Python:

```
>>> original = chr(192)
>>> print(original)
À
>>> broken = original.encode("utf-8").decode("cp1252")
>>> print(broken)
Ã€
>>> fixed = broken.encode("cp1252").decode("utf-8")
>>> fixed
À
>>> fixed == original
True
```

I don't have a Windows machine to test on at the moment, but this page describes how to decode the UTF-8 byte sequence to a Unicode codepoint using the `MultiByteToWideChar` function from `kernel32` and specifying codepage 65001 (which is UTF-8):
https://di-mgt.com.au/howto-convert-vba-unicode-to-utf8.html